# view.endEditing causing app to freeze on some textFields

Tags: swift

**Problem solved. See end of post.**

Sorry if this is a bit long but I'm hoping I've included as much info to get this solved.

***Brief overview of problem:*** Enter value in a textField using my custom keypad. Tap done button(should trigger view.endEditing) and some textFields will cause the app to freeze, most the time Xcode won't even throw an error but instead just restart the app, but i did catch one once(pic below). It works as expected on some textFields.

So I have a view controller with a bunch of textFields for the user to fill out which then performs calculations.

I have made a custom Keypad which essentially is the decimal pad with a "Done" button. I did this by making an keyboard.xib file and a keyboard.swift file.

Heres a snapshot of the error, I've included a whole bunch of my code below incase I'm using a method that isn't the best.

[image: Error Snapshot]

This is how the keyboard.swift file looks:

```
import UIKit

// The view controller will adopt this protocol (delegate)
// and thus must contain the keyWasTapped method
protocol KeyboardDelegate: class {
    func keyWasTapped(character: String)
    func keyDone()
    func backspace()
}

class keyboard: UIView {


    // This variable will be set as the view controller so that
    // the keyboard can send messages to the view controller.
    weak var delegate: KeyboardDelegate?

    // MARK:- keyboard initialization

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initializeSubviews()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initializeSubviews()
    }

    func initializeSubviews() {
        let xibFileName = "Keyboard" // xib extention not included
        let view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed(xibFileName, owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        self.addSubview(view)
        view.frame = self.bounds
    }

    // MARK:- Button actions from .xib file

    @IBAction func keyTapped(sender: UIButton) {
        // When a button is tapped, send that information to the
        // delegate (ie, the view controller)
        self.delegate?.keyWasTapped(sender.titleLabel!.text!) // could alternatively send a tag value
    }

    @IBAction func backspace(sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.backspace()
    }

    @IBAction func Done(sender: UIButton) {
        self.delegate?.keyDone()
    }


}
```

In the viewController I'm pretty sure I've included all the necessary things to access the keyboard seeing as it works for some textFields. Such as:

```
class myViewController: UITableViewController,UITextFieldDelegate, KeyboardDelegate
```

Then in viewDidLoad set each textField delegate:

```
            self.textField1.delegate = self
            self.textField2.delegate = self
            self.textField3.delegate = self

  // initialize custom keyboard
        let keyboardView = keyboard(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: numpad.height))
        keyboardView.delegate = self // the view controller will be notified by the keyboard whenever a key is tapped

        // replace system keyboard with custom keyboard
        textField1.inputView = keyboardView
        textField2.inputView = keyboardView
        textField3.inputView = keyboardView
```

Then this function (which seems to me to be the problem):

```
    func keyDone() {
        view.endEditing(true)
        //activeTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    print("please dont freeze")
    }
```

I have checked all the connections, they seem to be fine.

Let me know if I can add any more info to help work it out.
Many Thanks.

**Solved!!!**
I suppose ill just put it down to beating my head over it rather than taking a break from the screen! Still I'm confused why it wasn't given a more specific error.

The problem was that in some cases one of the functions was dividing by zero (this is undefined... not possible) but a good thing to take from this(thank you Olivier) is the Instruments Tools to help find where abouts the code was losing its mind. [This tutorial helped me understand how to use instruments!](http://www.xmcgraw.com/how-to-use-the-3-instruments-you-should-be-using/) So once I could see where it was going crazy I set up a bunch of print statements to watch the values as they went into the 'problem' calculation, where I found the denominator to be zero. Bit of rearranging the code around to avoid this and problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message is basically saying that there is a memory issue, try running the code with instruments (Allocations in particular) this might reveal is there is something amiss with your keyboard

Edit 2: for anyone finding this error message in future (actual solution in this case)

Double check any code code running after keyDone() to see if there are any infinite loops or situations that would cause the compiler to assume an infinite amount of memory is required. In this case a line of code was dividing by zero, causing a fatal memory error (unable to allocate the N/A value it generated)

Comment: hmm, gave that a go and it didn't solve, still just freezing. I'll have to have a read up on the instruments. Thanks for getting back!

Comment: Ok, it was a long shot anyways, it's probably a memory leak. Try debugging it using instruments.

Comment: Yep, I'm just having a read of that now. When the done button is pressed it does perform the calculate function which does about 80 lines of calcs, would that be enough to overload the memory?

Comment: Could be, it depends on the calculations! When you run instruments you you should be able to narrow down what is taking up so much memory! That is a good place to start though!

Comment: Maybe check that there are no infinite loops in your calculations. Maybe a particular situation is causing a loop to go on forever, that would certainly do it!

Comment: yeeeep, found it. there  was a sneaky little formula that divided by zero sometimes depending on inputs which explains why it was working in some places and not others! Thanks for setting me on the right path to find it!

Comment: No problem at all!

Comment: I'll edit my answer to be in line with the actual solution